# Select value from set of data

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a service where in a form I need the client to "begin typing" in their organization name and I need search results to appear. I was considering Select2 for bootstrap however I can't seem to find a function that fits my needs. If I could use Select2 that would be great, however the only problem is, my client should only be able to chose one name and not be able to select another. Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at [Twitter typeahead](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/)?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Just what I needed thank you very much! Please make this an answer so I can mark you as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few libraries that do this, including an open-source one by Twitter called [typeahead.js](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/), which in my experience is

1. Very fast
2. Optimized for large data sets (Think 10,000 options)
3. Highly customizable